# Conditional selection in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have following list with arrays:

```
[array([10,  1,  7,  3]),
 array([ 0, 14, 12, 13]),
 array([ 3, 10,  7,  8]),
 array([7, 5]),
 array([ 5, 12,  3]),
 array([14,  8, 10])]
```

What I want is to mark rows as "1" or "0", conditional on whether the row matches "10" AND "7" OR "10" AND "3".

```
np.where(output== 10 & output == 7 ) | (output == 10 & output == 3 ) | (output == 10 & output == 8 ), 1, 0)
```

returns

```
array(0)
```

What's the correct syntax to get into the array of the array?

**Expected output:**

```
[ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 ]
```

*Note:*
What is `output`? After training an CountVectorizer/LDA topic classifier in Scikit, the following script assigns topic probabilities to new documents. Topics above the threshold of 0.2 are then stored in an array.

```
def sortthreshold(x, thresh):
    idx = np.arange(x.size)[x > thresh]
    return idx[np.argsort(x[idx])]

output = []
for x in newdoc:
    y = lda.transform(bowvectorizer.transform([x]))
    output.append(sortthreshold(y[0], 0.2))
```

Thanks!

Comment: by mark did you mean to replace the value as 0 or 1?

Comment: That looks like a plain Python list of Numpy arrays. What's `output`?

Comment: Output is an array that is created out of an LDA topic model. The numbers in the array correspond to topics with a topic loading higher than a given threshold.

Comment: BTW, please don't use the string "10" when you mean the integer 10. It just adds confusion to your question.

Comment: What's your expect output? Can you paste some sample output?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Your code uses a variable named `output` that it hasn't defined. Is `output` supposed to be the name of the list defined at the start of your question?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, "output" is the name of that array which contains the other arrays. I will add the original function above in a second.

Comment: How come `[14,  8, 10]` matches? It has a 10, but no 7 or 3.

Comment: We (probably) don't need to see the original function that creates `output`. But we do need you to make the code you've shown us unambiguous and self-consistent. You keep calling `output` an array, but it looks like a list. And according to the code you just added, `output` _is_ a list, not an array.

Comment: @PM2Ring it matches 10 and 8: `| (output == 10 & output == 8 )`. And I think you are right. It's a list that contains arrays, right?

Comment: Yes, it's a list that contains arrays. BTW, it's a bit confusing to call your input data `output`. ;) The text of your question says you want to match rows that contain (10 and 7) or (10 and 3). But the code immediately following also attempts to match on (10 and 8). So you need to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `np.any` combined with `np.where`, and avoid using `|` and `&` which are binary operators in python.

```
import numpy as np

a = [np.array([10,  1,  7,  3]),
     np.array([ 0, 14, 12, 13]),
     np.array([ 3, 10,  7,  8]),
     np.array([7, 5]),
     np.array([ 5, 12,  3]),
     np.array([14,  8, 10])]

for output in a:
    print(np.where(((any(output == 10) and any(output == 7))) or 
                   (any(output == 10) and any(output == 3)) or
                   (any(output == 10) and any(output == 8 )), 1, 0))
```

#### output:

```
1
0
1
0
0
1
```

If you want it as a list as the edited question shows:

```
result = []
for output in a:
    result.append(1 if np.where(((any(output == 10) and any(output == 7))) or 
                   (any(output == 10) and any(output == 3)) or
                   (any(output == 10) and any(output == 8 )), 1, 0) == True else 0)

result
```

#### result:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: FWIW, in Numpy, `&` and `|` _can_ be used for logical operations. However, unlike `and` and `or` they do not short-circuit.

Comment: I did not know that about `&` and `|` with numpy, thank you @PM2Ring

Comment: @Christopher What Reblochon said about `|` and `&` in the first sentence is correct in plain Python, but it's not applicable to Numpy. However, there is no benefit in using  `|` and `&` for this task.

Comment: No worries. It is a little surprising. Of course, Numpy can't use the traditional C operators `&&` and `||` because the Python parser would reject them.

Comment: For some reason, my output of the first version is: `[array(1),
 array(0),
 array(1),
 array(0),
 array(0),...] `?

Comment: The first version prints a result for each sub array in a loop; it cannot be in a list, unless you tried to append it into a list. In this case, use the second version that converts the arrays into ints via their boolean value.

Comment: I just did some `timeit` tests. Your code is nearly twice as fast as my original version on the OP data.

Comment: hpaulj made a suggestion that _really_ speeds things up. I've added a `timeit` test to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your input data is a plain Python list of Numpy arrays of unequal length, thus it can't be simply converted to a 2D Numpy array, and so it can't be directly processed by Numpy. But it can be process using the usual Python list processing tools.

Here's a list comprehension that uses [`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html#numpy.isin) to test if a row contains any of (3, 7, 8). We first use simple `==` testing to see if the row contains 10, and only call `isin` if it does so; the Python `and` operator will not evaluate its second operand if the first operand is false-ish.

We use [`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html#numpy.any) to see if any row item passes each test. `np.any` returns a Boolean value of `False` or `True`, but we can pass those values to `int` to convert them to 0 or 1.

```
import numpy as np

data = [
    np.array([10, 1, 7, 3]), np.array([0, 14, 12, 13]),
    np.array([3, 10, 7, 8]), np.array([7, 5]),
    np.array([5, 12, 3]), np.array([14, 8, 10]),
]

mask = np.array([3, 7, 8])
result = [int(np.any(row==10) and np.any(np.isin(row, mask)))
    for row in data]

print(result)
```

**output**

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

---

I've just performed some [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) tests. Curiously, Reblochon Masque's code is faster on the data given in the question, presumably because of the short-circuiting behaviour of plain Python `any`, `and` & `or`. Also, it appears that [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d) is faster than `numpy.isin`, even though the docs recommend using the latter in new code.

Here's a new version that's about 10% slower than Reblochon's.

```
mask = np.array([3, 7, 8])
result = [int(any(row==10) and any(np.in1d(row, mask)))
    for row in data]
```

Of course, the true speed on large amounts of real data may vary from what my tests indicate. And time may not be an issue: even on my slow old 32 bit single core 2GHz machine I can process the data in the question almost 3000 times in one second.

---

hpaulj has suggested an even faster way. Here's some [timeit test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat) info, comparing the various versions. These tests were performed on my old machine, YMMV.

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import Timer

the_data = [
    np.array([10, 1, 7, 3]), np.array([0, 14, 12, 13]),
    np.array([3, 10, 7, 8]), np.array([7, 5]),
    np.array([5, 12, 3]), np.array([14, 8, 10]),
]

def rebloch0(data):
    result = []
    for output in data:
        result.append(1 if np.where((any(output == 10) and any(output == 7)) or
            (any(output == 10) and any(output == 3)) or
            (any(output == 10) and any(output == 8)), 1, 0) == True else 0)
    return result

def rebloch1(data):
    result = []
    for output in data:
        result.append(1 if np.where((any(output == 10) and any(output == 7)) or
            (any(output == 10) and any(output == 3)) or
            (any(output == 10) and any(output == 8)), 1, 0) else 0)
    return result

def pm2r0(data):
    mask = np.array([3, 7, 8])
    return [int(np.any(row==10) and np.any(np.isin(row, mask)))
        for row in data]

def pm2r1(data):
    mask = np.array([3, 7, 8])
    return [int(any(row==10) and any(np.in1d(row, mask)))
        for row in data]

def hpaulj0(data):
    mask=np.array([3, 7, 8])
    return [int(any(row==10) and any((row[:, None]==mask).flat))
        for row in data]

def hpaulj1(data, mask=np.array([3, 7, 8])):
    return [int(any(row==10) and any((row[:, None]==mask).flat))
        for row in data]

functions = (
    rebloch0,
    rebloch1,
    pm2r0,
    pm2r1,
    hpaulj0,
    hpaulj1,
)

# Verify that all functions give the same result
for func in functions:
    print('{:8}: {}'.format(func.__name__, func(the_data)))
print()

def time_test(loops, data):
    timings = []
    for func in functions:
        t = Timer(lambda: func(data))
        result = sorted(t.repeat(3, loops))
        timings.append((result, func.__name__))
    timings.sort()
    for result, name in timings:
        print('{:8}: {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}'.format(name, *result))
    print()

time_test(1000, the_data)
```

**typical output**

```
rebloch0: [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
rebloch1: [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
pm2r0   : [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
pm2r1   : [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
hpaulj0 : [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
hpaulj1 : [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

hpaulj1 : 0.140421, 0.154910, 0.156105
hpaulj0 : 0.154224, 0.154822, 0.167101
rebloch1: 0.281700, 0.282764, 0.284599
rebloch0: 0.339693, 0.359127, 0.375715
pm2r1   : 0.367677, 0.368826, 0.371599
pm2r0   : 0.626043, 0.628232, 0.670199
```

Nice work, hpaulj!

Comment: A blending of these ideas is even faster: `int(any(arr==10) and any((arr[:,None]==[3,7,8]).flat))`

Comment: @hpaulj Wow, that's impressive!